# Raw RGB values to JPEG

Tags: c++, image, jpeg, rgb

I have an array with raw RGB values in it, and I need to write these values to a JPEG file. Is there an easy way to do this?

[image]

I tried:

```
std::ofstream ofs("./image.JPG", std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);

for (unsigned i = 0; i < width * height; ++i) {
   ofs << (int)(std::min(1.0f, image[i].x) * 255) << (int)(std::min(1.0f, image[i].y) * 255) << (int)(std::min(1.0f, image[i].z) * 255);
}
```

but the format isn't recognized.

Comment: Have you looked at the JPEG spec? Alternatively, `libjpeg` is a popular choice if you don't want to encode the data by hand (which I advise you don't).

Comment: Err... The whole "JPEG format" thing aside, are you trying to make a single JPEG that is one pixel high and X pixels wide? If not, how is the JPEG supposed to know how to wrap your lines of pixels into an image?

Comment: @meagar no, that's just the format of the data I'm storing.

Comment: @Cameron I looked at that but I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: Then... why does it need to be JPEG?

Comment: @meagar is there an easier format to write to?

Comment: @TylerSebastian That question doesn't make sense. Why do you think you need a "format"? Are or are you not trying to produce an image that people can view with a JPEG viewer? Do you just want to store a bunch of arbitrary bytes to be read in later or do you want to *generate an image*, viewable outside your program?

Comment: @meagar I'd like my image to be viewable outside my program.

Comment: Then... you need to answer my question. Are you trying to produce a 1 pixel high image? Or does your image have actual dimensions? If it has dimensions, how do you expect JPEG to know how to figure that out if you're just writing a stream of bytes representing RGB values? If you write 6 bytes, that could be a 1x6, a 2x3, a 3x2 or a 6x1 image. JPEG can't just *know* that, you have to provide that data.

Comment: @meagar it has dimensions

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to produce an image file you might look at [Netpbm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm). You could write the intermediate format (PBM or PAM) fairly simply from what you have. There are then a large number of already written programs that will generate many types of images from your intermediate file.

Answer (score 0):

WOH THERE!

JPEG is MUCH more complicated than raw RBG values. You are going to need to use a library, like LIBJPEG, to store the data as JPEG.

If you wrote it yourself you'd have to:

1. Convert from RGB to YCbCr
2. Sample the image
3. Divide into 8x8 blocks.
4. Perform the DCT on each block.
5. Run-length/huffman encode the values
6. Write these values in properly formatted JPEG blocks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Boost GIL](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/gil/doc/index.html): it's free, portable (it's part of Boost libraries), usable across a broad spectrum of operating systems (including Windows).

Popular Linux and Unix distributions such as Fedora, Debian and NetBSD include pre-built Boost packages.

The code is quite simple:

```
#include <boost/gil/extension/io/jpeg_io.hpp>

const unsigned width  = 320;
const unsigned height = 200;

// Raw data.
unsigned char r[width * height];  // red
unsigned char g[width * height];  // green
unsigned char b[width * height];  // blue

int main()
{
  boost::gil::rgb8c_planar_view_t view =
    boost::gil::planar_rgb_view(width, height, r, g, b, width);

  boost::gil::jpeg_write_view("out.jpg", view);

  return 0;
}
```

[jpeg_write_view](http://stlab.adobe.com/gil/html/group___j_p_e_g___i_o.html#ga2) saves the currently instantiated view to a jpeg file specified by the name (throws `std::ios_base::failure` if it fails to create the file).

Remember to link your program with `-ljpeg`.